# Relational patterns switch statement performance

Tags: c#, switch-statement, pattern-matching, c#-9.0

So for normal C# switch statements when they get long enough, they usually compile to something O(1). Much like a dictionary lookup for the value in a sense, to just to the code you want.

Now with C# 9.0, we have Relational patterns, which allow you to essentially define matching ranges in a switch case.
Now I was left wondering, does it under the hood unroll those into the O(1) lookup once more, or is it not smart enough to do so, and instead turns into a bunch of "if" statements to check the values?

I can't seem to find a hard answer to this question, and it could be important for things where you would want the switch statement to be performant.

Any insight and reasoning would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At least in *some* cases where the switch case uses patterns, the compiler is smart enough to figure this out, and output a `switch` IL instruction (or in your words, the "O(1) lookup").

We can investigate this using [SharpLab.io](http://sharplab.io/), which shows the IL that the compiler outputs given some C# code.

For example, it is able to output a `switch` instruction in the following cases:

```
switch (x) {
    case 1 or 2 or 3:
        Console.WriteLine("1");
        break;
    case 4 or 5 or 6:
        Console.WriteLine("2");
        break;
    case 7 or 8 or 9:
        Console.WriteLine("3");
        break;
    default:
        break;
}
```

```
switch (x) {
    case 1:
        Console.WriteLine("1");
        break;
    case 4 or 5 or 6:
        Console.WriteLine("2");
        break;
    case 7 or 8 or 9:
        Console.WriteLine("3");
        break;
    default:
        break;
}
```

Example IL:

```
IL_0000: ldarg.1 // load x
IL_0001: ldc.i4.1 // load 1
IL_0002: sub // x - 1

// go to any of these instructions depending on the value of x - 1
IL_0003: switch (IL_002d, IL_002d, IL_002d, IL_0038, IL_0038, IL_0038, IL_0043, IL_0043, IL_0043)

// default case
IL_002c: ret

...
```

However, it doesn't output a `switch` if you rewrite this using `<=` and `>=` (relational patterns):

```
switch (x) {
    case >= 1 and <= 3:
        Console.WriteLine("1");
        break;
    case >= 4 and <= 6:
        Console.WriteLine("2");
        break;
    case >= 7 and <= 9:
        Console.WriteLine("3");
        break;
    default:
        break;
}
```

Example IL (you can see that the relational patterns get translated into conditional jumps, such as `bgt`, `blt` etc):

```
IL_0000: ldarg.1
IL_0001: ldc.i4.6
IL_0002: bgt.s IL_000e

IL_0004: ldarg.1
IL_0005: ldc.i4.1
IL_0006: blt.s IL_0034

IL_0008: ldarg.1
IL_0009: ldc.i4.3
IL_000a: ble.s IL_0014

IL_000c: br.s IL_001f

IL_000e: ldarg.1
IL_000f: ldc.i4.s 9
IL_0011: ble.s IL_002a

IL_0013: ret

...
```

Comment: Whether that actually makes a difference to the JIT assembly is another question, and whether any such difference makes a difference to performance is an even bigger question.

Comment: I can only assume jump instructions are more pricey, but thanks for the resource, looks like a great way to check what can be done and what can not.
Sad about it not "getting" the >= < variants though.

Comment: @Smileynator I wouldn't just "assume" that. I recommend testing with [Benchmark.NET](https://benchmarkdotnet.org) if you want to see the actual performance differences. More likely than not, it's not going to be noticeable for just a few switch cases. Furthermore, as Charlieface has suggested, even if the C# compiler doesn't notice the pattern, the JIT compiler might do.

Comment: Fair, assuming you are writing something huge like a bytecode interpreter, this is relevant to research though, so i will.